# `ggplot2 - facet_grid`: Axes without ticks in interior facets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, facet-grid

I would like to create `facet_grid` / `facet_wrap` plot with the x axis being repeated under each graph but with ticks present only on the lowest graph.

Here is an example of a plot with the x axis present only once using `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg,x=cyl)) + 
  facet_grid(am~., scales="free") + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Here is an example of a plot with the x axis present twice but with ticks both times using `facet_wrap`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) + 
  facet_wrap(~am, ncol=1, scales="free") + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

I would like the same plot as the one just above but without the ticks on the x-axis of the upper graph. Or if you prefer, I would like the same plot as the first one but with an x-axis on the upper graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very verbose solution, but I don't think you can get the plot you want using just the usual `ggplot` functions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

Plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) + 
  facet_wrap(~am, ncol=1, scales="free") + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Switching off the top x-axis requires modifying the gtable object for the plot.

```
Plot.build <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(Plot))
axis.pos <- grep("axis-b-1-1", Plot.build$layout$name)
num.ticks <- length(Plot.build$grobs[[axis.pos]]$children[2]$axis$grobs[[1]]$y)
```

This step removes the axis labels:

```
Plot.build$grobs[[axis.pos]]$children$axis$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]]$label <- rep("", num.ticks)
```

This step removes the tick marks:

```
Plot.build$grobs[[axes.pos]]$children[2]$axis$grobs[[1]]$y <- rep(unit(0, units="cm"), num.ticks)
```

Finally, the plot is generated using:

```
grid.draw(Plot.build)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I use to get just an axis line (no tick marks) is to use `geom_hline()` to fake an axis.

```
#make a dataframe with the y minimum for each facet
fake.axes <- data.frame(mpg = c(10, 15), #y minimum to use for axis location
                    am = c(0,1)) #facetting variable

#add an "axis" without ticks to upper graph using geom_hline()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg,x=cyl)) + 
  facet_grid(am~., scales="free") + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mpg), fake.axes, #dataframe with fake axes 
         linetype = c("solid", "blank")) + #line for top graph, blank for bottom graph
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]
If you haven't used `scales = "free"`, and all the axes are in the same location this is even simpler, you can skip making a dataframe with yintercepts for each facet and simply add
`geom_hline(yintercept = 10)` (or whatever your minimum is) to your plot code to add an axis line on each facet.